# JAVA многомерный массив ввода чисел с клавиатуры, вложенный цикл

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, матрицы

Не могу настроить работу вложенного цикла, введенное число с клавиатуры записывает в один массив с постоянным ее повторением в то время когда должна происходить итерация после каждого ввода числа до окончания ячеек и в итоге выйти матрица с разними значениями которые задал пользователь. Помогите пожалуйста исправить проблему)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = new int[5][5];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input array elements:");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < array[5][5]; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < array[5][5]; j++)
            array[i][j] = num;
    }

    System.out.print("Inserted array elements:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[i][i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: для ввода: `for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)`, для вывода добавить такой же вложенный цикл

Comment: Будет ли выполняться хоть один `for` цикл при условии `for (int i = 0; i < array[5][5]; i++)`??  При инициализации весь массив `array` заполняется нулями.