# вывод квадратной матрицы. заполнение с клавиатуры

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

Должно выводить квадратною матрицу,но выводит либо строкой, либо столбиком. Еще нужна помощь с заполнением матрицы, каждую ячейку пользователь должен заполнять своим числом но в настоящее время телеки один раз проводится итерация и почти все ячейки заполняются одним и тем же числом. Помогите пожалуйста устранить проблемы))))

```
    int [][]array= new int[5][5];

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введіть числ щоб заповнити масив: ");
    int num = in.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Input array elements:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < 5; j++)
            array[i][j] = num;
    }

    System.out.println("The array 5x5: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            System.out.println(" " + array[i][j]); //виведення масиву
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы видите код, но не имеете понятия, что он делает? Попробуйте построчно разобраться в коде, что каждая строка делает, так и поймёте что поменять. Задача то не сложная.

Comment: @tym3267 я только начала свой путь в этой сфере, очевидные вам вещи мне еще не совсем ясны)

Comment: Ну в этом и суть обучения. В чем польза, если вам просто напишут ответ? Мне кажется, полезней дойти до решения самостоятельно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JAVA многомерный массив ввода чисел с клавиатуры, вложенный цикл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1359054/java-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb)

Comment: @tym3267, я стараюсь, учусь но иногда нужно чтобы указали на ошибку и подсказали правильный путь к решению

Comment: Дам несколько подсказок Вам. 1) Если элементы массива получают одинаковые значение, значит где-то им присаивается это значение. Переменная `num` меняет свое значение в цикле? 2) Если индексы первого элемента первой строки `[0][0]`, то индексы первого элемента второй строки `[1][0]`, а с какого элемента начинает цикл со счётчиком `j`? 3) По поводу вывода могу посоветовать почитать про разницу между `print` и `println` и подумат как бы их так использовать чтобы получить вывод в виде матрицы.

Comment: @EOF спасибо большое